# Azure function set expiration time for queue output

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

Is it possible to set an expiration time for Azure Function Storage queue output binding?

This is what I have in function.js:

{
  "type": "queue",
  "name": "MyMessageQueue",
  "queueName": "mymsgqueue",
  "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
  "direction": "out"
}

However can I specify when the message I add should expire?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Function used to write to queue - can I set metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472725/azure-function-used-to-write-to-queue-can-i-set-metadata)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. In your function's `Run` method, change the `MyMessageQueue` output parameter type to [CloudQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue). Then create a [CloudQueueMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueuemessage) in your code and use the [AddMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage) method to add the message to the queue. The `timeToLive` parameter would allow you to control the expiration time.

Refer to the [Azure Functions Queue Storage bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue) documentation page for more details and examples.

Comment: I don't see ExpirationTime as a settable property on CloudQueueMessage. Could you tell me if I'm missing something?

Comment: This doesn't work. You have to bind to CloudQueue class instead, see duplicate question link above.

Comment: @Mikhail is right - you'll need to use CloudQueue. I'll update the answer.